# Noob Javascript auto total

Tags: javascript

Apologies for what I'm sure is a rather simple javascript question, but how would I get the following total funtion to calculate the total every time a cost is entered into the table, i.e. without having to press the total button to submit the form.

```
function totalIt() {
  var qtys = document.getElementsByName("qty[]");
  var total=0;
  for (var i=1;i<=qtys.length;i++) {
    calc(i);  
    var price = parseFloat(document.getElementById("price"+i).value);
    total += isNaN(price)?0:price;
  }
  document.getElementById("total").value=isNaN(total)?"0.00":total.toFixed(2);                        
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/jDfFU/

Comment: Run the function from the `change` event of the `cost` input fields.

Comment: Just call the function from whatever code is adding a cost to the table. Without more information, we can't really give you a better answer than that. If the costs are being entered into `input`s by users, hook the `change` (and/or possibly `input`) event.

Comment: I'm intrigued. The fiddle is in mplungjan's account, but you don't appear to be [mplungjan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan).

Comment: Indeed I am not mplungjan, what is the correct t etiquette here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF the `qty` fields are where the costs are being entered, then in your setup code, just hook `totalIt` up to the `change` (and possibly `input`, if you want immediate feedback) events:

```
var qtys = document.getElementsByName("qty[]");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < qtys.length; ++i) {
    qtys[i].addEventListener("change", totalIt, false);
    qtys[i].addEventListener("input", totalIt, false);
}
```

On modern browsers, if you hook `input`, you don't need to hook `change`; the above just allows for the possibility of older browsers by hooking `change` in case they don't support `input`.